# Is it possible to install a ROM from TWRP ADB shell?

Tags: adb, twrp

Let's say I place a rom in `/sdcard/`. Can I install in the ADB shell through TWRP. For instance, if I

- Start up in recovery of TWRP
- Type in on the host `adb shell`

Is there anyway to install `/sdcard/rom.zip`

Comment: What's the deal? Is TWRP unusable normally from touchscreen?

Comment: No, I can use it. I just want a log and I want to see what's running that process so I can potentially get a log. TWRP doesn't tell me much and it's apparently not working. (or the roms just don't boot at all)

Comment: I don't think that'd give you details - look into `recovery.log` and probably `dmesg`. Also, just a hunch, but you might want to try an older version of TWRP, e.g. 3.0.2. I just remembered that I had problems in the past on another Samsung tablet with the latest available there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TWRP provides a command line utility called `twrp` and the official site has a [guide to `twrp`'s subcommands](https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html) of which the command needed is simply `install`

> ```
> install FILENAME :
>
>     install FILENAME zip file.
> ```

Usage: under `adb shell` environment, run

```
twrp install /path/to/rom.zip
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, complains about `Zip signature verification failed!` any idea?

Comment: @JPT Irrelevant - check the zip itself.

Comment: `twrp` command is not exists for me.